# intent.getAction() is null

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I'm doing a NFC APP with Android studio, but when I scan the NFC Tag, the intent is null.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  // Detección del adaptador
  nfcAdapter=NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

  // Detección de etiqueta en primer plano
  pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(
      this, 
      0, 
      new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
      PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

  // Aviso de detección NFC desactivada
  if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Detección Nfc desactivada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  TagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
  TagDetected.addCategory(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
  TagDetected.addCategory(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
  TagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
  writingTagIntent = new IntentFilter[]{TagDetected};
}

private void readForIntent(Intent intent) {
  Log.d("NFC", "Intent Action: " + intent.getAction());
  if (!NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())
      && !NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())
      && !NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Tag tag;
    tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    if (tag != null) {
      handleNfcIntent(tag);
    }
  }
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  setIntent(intent);
  Log.d("NFC", "onNewIntent: " + intent.getAction());
  readForIntent(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  WritemodeOff();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  WritemodeOn();
}

private void WritemodeOn() {
  if (nfcAdapter!=null) {
    NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)
      .enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writingTagIntent, null);
  }
}

private void WritemodeOff() {
  if (nfcAdapter != null) {
    nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
  }
}
```

I wanna know how to change the intent value